# The below code is giving 'UnreadVariable' error in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, gradienttape

```
# importing libraries
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.losses import MSE

# creating keras model
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(Dense(8, input_shape=(1,), activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))

# defining optimization parameters
opt=Adam(learning_rate = 1e-3)

# creating input and output variables for training
X = np.arange(1.,10.,1).reshape(-1,1)
Y = np.arange(2.,20.,2).reshape(-1,1)

# defining loss - only one iteration is performed
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    pred = model(X)
    loss = MSE(pred, Y)

# calculating gradients for loss w.r.t model parameters 
grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)

# updating model parameters with above calculated gradients
opt.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))
```

I am getting the following error :

```
tf.Variable 'UnreadVariable' shape=() dtype=int64, numpy=1
```

I have tried : `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()` to disable eager tensor execution but I can't extract the values of any tensor post that. Also I don't know whether disabling eagerTensor actually solves the issue since I can't print the gradients or losses.

Comment: Please post a [mre]

Comment: I have added the comments to explain each line of code. Also only one iteration is performed.

Comment: Are "model.trainable_variables" being updated

Answer (score 2):

If you print your trainable weights before and after applying the gradients, you will clearly see that they are updated, even if it is only a small push to the right or left:

```py
grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
tf.print(model.trainable_variables)
opt.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))
tf.print(model.trainable_variables)
```

Comment: Thanks..I tried the same and its working..